# how to save a file in the directory you are currently in (COSMOS)

Tags: c#, file, cosmos

So I'm making a Cosmos OS and I am having some trouble. I have this code that makes a file. what it does is it asks What is the name of the file and extension then what is the files contents then makes the file. The Problem is is that it only saves to main directory of 0:\ and doesn't work when you make a file while in a directory like 0:\TEST. This is the code I have for the file creator. I want to know if it's possible to make it save the file to the directory you are currently in.

```
 Console.Write("File Name (put in the extension name):");
                var finput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                string fileName = finput;
                // Check if file already exists. If yes, delete it.     
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileName);
                }
                Console.Write("File Contents:\n");
                var text = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
                {
                    // Add some text to file    
                    Byte[] title = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(text);
                    fs.Write(title, 0, title.Length);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("File Made!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a late answer, but try this:

```
var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory;
var file = (filename);
File.Create(dir + "\\" + file);
```

I haven't checked this code but it should be something like this.  This (should) do the same as your code above.